# Django REST Framework serializer field is required even when required=False

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this

```
class FalseUserAnswer(BaseModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(TrueOrFalseQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_question = models.ForeignKey(TrueOrFalseUserQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(FalseAnswer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the problem is one old version of my frontend does not send `user_question` while the newer one does. So, I want to accept an object that **does not have** the field at all (it will not be null, or None or nothing, just won't be in the request).

I tried to do something like this in my serializer

```
class FalseUserAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Allows null for version < 1.18 of the app. Might be removed in the future.
    user_question = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=TrueOrFalseUserQuestion.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FalseUserAnswer
        fields = ['id', 'creator', 'question', 'user_question', 'answer', 'type']
```

But I still get

```
"error": {
        "user_question": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
}
```

Django REST framework version is 3.8.2

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: PrimaryKeyRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key if  required-Flase then no use right? i think for PrimaryKeyRelatedField  it is mondataory

Comment: @HemanthSP it makes sense in some situations, in mine it's because the field was added after some iterations and the app is already running in production. But you could image someone using a web app where the user can fill a form completely in one page, and in a mobile app it has to be in two or three pages and you store in DB at each step and patch the data after it (so the user does not have to complete everything again if app is left or if app crashes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I read the source code, and apparently to get the behaviour I want, I must set the default value to None. Does not makes sense since I believed it would be the fallback value once I say required=False (and the database field should be filled with NULL).

So previously my code was

```
user_question = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=TrueOrFalseUserQuestion.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True)
```

The working version is

```
user_question = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=TrueOrFalseUserQuestion.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: IMO this makes no sense how this works and after coming to the same conclusion i wanted to confirm i wasn't alone with this issue.

Comment: For my use case, it was just the queryset=..., many=True and required=False that was needed. In the OP, it mentioned not needing to be null, so I don't you needed the extra params.